# Automate the Boring Stuff With Python randomQuizGenerator Errors

Tags: python, automation

I am new to Python and am trying to create a random generator quiz from "Automate the Boring Stuff With Python". My code keeps telling me ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. What does that mean and how can I fix it? Code for reference.

```
quizFile.write(f'{questionNum + 1}. What is the capital of {states[questionNum]}?\n')
for i in range(4):
quizFile.write(f"{'ABCD'[i]}.{answerOptions[i]}\n")
quizFile.write('\n')

#Write the answer key to a file

answerKeyFile.write(f"{questionNum + 1}.{'ABCD'[answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]}")
quizFile.close()
answerKeyFile.close()
```

I am really new to programming so I am looking forward to your insight. Please and thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the exception you are seeing and the code that defines `quizFile` and `answerKeyFile`?

Answer (score 2):

Move your `quizFile.close()` and `answerKeyFile.close()` outside of the for loop. As seen below:

--snip--

## Loop through all 50 states, making a question for each.

```
for questionNum in range(50):
    # Get the right and wrong answers.
    correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
    wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
    del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
    wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
    answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
    random.shuffle(answerOptions)

    # Write the question and the answer ooptions to the quiz file.
    quizFile.write('%s. What is the capital of %s\n' % (questionNum + 1,
        states[questionNum]))
    for i in range(4):
        quizFile.write(' %s. %s\n' % ('ABCD'[i], answerOptions[i]))
        quizFile.write('\n')

        # Write the answer key to a file.
        answerKeyFile.write('%s. %s\n' % (questionNum + 1, 'ABCD'
            [answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]))
quizFile.close()
answerKeyFile.close()
```

Hope this helps. I too am new, but this made it work for me. You are changing the fact that the "files" were closing after the first loop through. I'm sure someone more experienced will have a better and clearer explanation. So, for those more knowledgeable, please don't blast me.